# Linked and Related questions does not display at right side area of question page

Tags: discussion, related-questions, linked-questions

Hi everyone i am facing one issue in SO official site.

I just select one question and before a week i show in SO site that at right side area it'll display related questions in **Linked** and **Related** section.

**Before: Linked and Related question section is display..**

[image]

**and now some times: It wont display Linked and Related section.**

[image]

So, i am little confuses that it's happen to me only or is that a kind of new updates in SO.

Give me any suggestion on this.

Comment: I've noticed for the past few weeks that many questions don't have **Related** lists. I haven't figured out the pattern.